# How do I query the result of an inner join query?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Good day,

Goal - I need to fetch data from 3 different tables to get my desired result.
2 of the 3 tables match. i.e. there is no common field in all 3 tables

What I've tried - In the code below you will see that I've done an inner join on first 2 tables to get a field that I can link with the 3rd table.  I'm not sure how to execute the subquery function to get the desired result.

```
'''select * from [dbo].[CombinedPet&DieMRN#$]
inner join [dbo].['Annex A Selby M 20200701$'] on [MRN No]=[MRN Number (PoE-Date-Final #)]
(
Select * from [dbo].['5839 EY Acquitted Trans$'][BP Ref]
inner join [dbo].[CombinedPet&DieMRN#$]
on [BP Ref]=[File Reference])
)'''
```

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you need to be much more precise if you want any answers. You've posted what you've tried so far but have not explained what the problem is with it. In your goal you say that you want to fetch data from 3 different tables- you don't need a subquery for that.

Comment: ....If you still want to keep the subquery you need to "treat it as a normal join" and add add " join" before it as well as an on clause after it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure how to create a permanent join.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Some context, I'm using these tables to query data from different sources, which I've imported as different tables. I create queries to link the tables and get the desired result.

Comment: What happens if you try this?
select *
from [dbo].[CombinedPet&DieMRN#$]
inner join [dbo].['Annex A Selby M 20200701$'] on [MRN No]=[MRN Number (PoE-Date-Final #)]
inner join [dbo].['5839 EY Acquitted Trans$'] on [BP Ref]=[File Reference]

Comment: The query runs but there is no result i.e. shows field headings but no data           However if I run the first 2 lines of the code I do get a result.'''select * from [dbo].[CombinedPet&DieMRN#$] inner join [dbo].['Annex A Selby M 20200701$'] on [MRN No]=[MRN Number (PoE-Date-Final #)]'''